# Copying opencart 3.0.2.0 site from live to localhost for development

Tags: php, apache2, opencart

I want to create a full copy of a live opencart website on my local drive and run it on localhost so I can test additions and changes. Simply copying all files through ftp won't do it. Does anyone have access to documentation on how I could do this?

I'm currently trying to do this in a lamp stack on ubuntu 16.04lt through vmplayer 12 on host windows 10 computer. Thanks for any input.

Comment: _Simply copying all files through ftp won't do it_ Why is that?

Comment: Also you need to backup a database. I suppose opencart has tools to backup it's database.

Comment: @u_mulder 
It won't work since there are config.php files in the public_html and admin folder which specify domain names and in many other files.
I also have a backed up database, but not through opencart. I set it up through godaddy. Whenever I exported the database through the opencart cms I got a truncated sql file which would throw errors whenever i tried to import it through phpmyadmin

Comment: update the config files. There are just two files. config.php and admin/config.php and you just have to update the domain with virtual host details and it should work

Comment: @MehravishTemkar- Thank you for your advice. I've updated config.php and admin config.php to reflect my localhost domain change. I can now view my front page which is a huge improvement. I however cannot view any of the links or the /shop/. All links 404 and I believe it to be related to .htaccess files or SEO. The shop leads to a connection refused.
Thank you again regardless for the information

Comment: @mcmcphillips https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=118550 this thread might help

Comment: Thank you @MehravishTemkar. I actually referenced this thread a few times. It was a very similar issue to what I've been experiencing. Thank you.